# I was doing a drag and drop system and it does not work as I want

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

ok here the script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InventoryManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject SlotHandler;
    [SerializeField] private ItemClass itemToAdd;
    [SerializeField] private ItemClass itemToRemove;

    [SerializeField] SlotClass[] startItems;
    SlotClass[] items;

    private GameObject[] Slots;

    private void Start()
    {
        Slots = new GameObject[SlotHandler.transform.childCount];
        items = new SlotClass[Slots.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            items[i] = new SlotClass();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < startItems.Length; i++)
        {
            items[i] = startItems[i];
        }



        for (int i = 0; i < SlotHandler.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            Slots[i] = SlotHandler.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        }

        refreshUI();

        addItem(itemToAdd);
       removeItem(itemToRemove);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Debug.Log(GetClosetSlot());
        }
    }

    #region Inventory Utils
    public void refreshUI()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Slots.Length; i++)
        {
           
            try
            {
               Slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = items[i].GetItem().itemSprite;
               Slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
               Slots[i].transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = items[i]._GetCantidad() + "";
               if (Slots[i].transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text == "1")
               {
                   Slots[i].transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = string.Empty;
               }
            }
            catch
            {
               Slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = null;
               Slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;
               Slots[i].transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
    public bool addItem(ItemClass item)
    {
        SlotClass slot = Contains(item);

        if (slot != null && slot.GetItem()._isStackable)
        {
            slot.MasCantidad(1);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                if (items[i].GetItem() == null)
                {
                    items[i].Addition(item, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }

   /*         if (items.Count < Slots.Length)
                items.Add(new SlotClass(item, 1));
            else
                return false;*/
        }

        refreshUI();
        return true;
    }
    public bool removeItem(ItemClass item)
    {
        SlotClass Temp = Contains(item);

        if (Temp != null)
        {
            if (Temp._GetCantidad() > 1)
            {
               Temp.menosCantidad(1);
            }
            else
            {
                int slotToRemoveIndex = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (items[i].GetItem() == item)
                    {
                        slotToRemoveIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                items[slotToRemoveIndex].clear();
            }

        }
        else
        { 
            return false; 
        }

        refreshUI();
        return true;
    } 
    public SlotClass Contains(ItemClass item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].GetItem() == item)
            {
                return items[i];
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    #endregion Invetory Utils

    #region Moving Stuff
    private SlotClass GetClosetSlot()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Slots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Vector2.Distance(Slots[i].transform.position, Input.mousePosition) < -10)
                return items[i];
        }

        return null;
    }
    #endregion
```

The problem is that I'm wanting to make unity read the UI Planes through the GetClosetSlot() function and I put a debug.log to it to tell me if the position of my mouse matches that of my UI Plane, but I click outside the UI Plane and if it works correctly it says "Null" or nothing, until you click inside them and you realize that it keeps saying the same thing, "Null" and everything is fine.

By the way I am using unity 2021.3.23f1 LTS.

everything is practically the same as the video I'm watching but it doesn't work and I can't prove anything because I don't know

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking if your mouse is "within" a certain UI item - you are only checking if the

```
Vector2.Distance(Slots[i].transform.position, Input.mousePosition) < -10
```

which means your cursor would not be allowed to be more than 10 pixels away from the **pivot point** of that UI item.

You rather can use

```
RectTransform[] Slots;
Camera camera;
```

and initialize it once

```
camera = Camera.main;

for (int i = 0; i < SlotHandler.transform.childCount; i++)
{
    Slots[i] = SlotHandler.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<RectTransform>();
}
```

or alternatively you could also use

```
using System.Linq;

...

Slots = SlotHandler.transform.Cast<RectTransform>().ToArray();
```

and then you can check for

```
for (int i = 0; i < Slots.Length; i++)
{
    var slot = Slots[i];
    
    if (RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint(slot, Input.mousePosition, camera)
    {
        return items[i];
    }
}
```

---

Btw to save some resources this

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    items[i] = new SlotClass();
}
for (int i = 0; i < startItems.Length; i++)
{
    items[i] = startItems[i];
}
```

can be simplified to

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    items[i] = i < startItems.Length ? startItems[i] : new SlotClass();
}
```

---

For the `refreshUI` I would also strongly recommend to rather have a dedicated component for your Slots where all the further required ones are referenced.

This would also allow you to above simply do

```
Slots = SlotHandler.GetComponentsInChildren<YourSlotComponent>();
```